# Google Script for loop not running

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to check duplicate from org array with chg array.
If there is no duplicate push value to temp array.

```
  function uList(org, chg){
    //return a unique list
    var org ;
    var chg ;
    var temp ;

    for(var i=0;i<=org.legnth;i++){ 
      for(var j=0;j<=chg.length;j++){
         if(org[i][0]==chg[j][0]){
           if(temp.length>0) {temp.pop();}

         }else{
           temp.push(org[i][0]);


         }
      }

    }
      return temp;
 }
```

**Entire Code**  is show below.

```
   function onEdit(e){
 // Browser.msgBox("test");
  updateForm();
    }

  function uList(org, chg){
    //return a unique list
    var org ;
    var chg ;
    var temp ;

    for(var i=0;i<=org.legnth;i++){ 
      for(var j=0;j<=chg.length;j++){
         if(org[i][0]==chg[j][0]){
           if(temp.length>0) {temp.pop();}

         }else{
           temp.push(org[i][0]);


         }
      }

    }
      return temp;
 } 



 function updateForm(){ // select list from name
  // call your form and connect to the drop-down item
  var form = FormApp.openById("");
  var namesList = form.getItemById("").asListItem(); //data-item-id

// identify the sheet where the data resides needed to populate the drogp-down// Mask_order (responses)
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/').getSheetByName("");
  var names =ss;
  var namesValues =names.getRange("F2:F").getValues();//desired dorpdown list
  var total=names.getRange("H2").getValue();//Define COUNTA
  var org_list=names.getRange("E2:E").getValues();//original list
  var chg_list=names.getRange("D2:D").getValues();//Redeem list
  var the_list=uList(org_list,chg_list);



  //var thelist=uList(org_list,chg_list);
  // names.getRange("F2").setValue("2");

  var temp=form.getItemById("").setHelpText("No. of :"+total)// Mask redeem  help text.
      debugger;
    var studentNames = [];




  // convert the array ignoring empty cells
  for(var i = 0; i < namesValues.length; i++)   
    if(namesValues[i][0] != "")
      studentNames[i] = namesValues[i][0];

  // populate the drop-down with the array data
  namesList.setChoiceValues(studentNames);

    }
```

In Google script Debug mode, a temp is an object with no data.

I attempted to put debugger everywhere and it did not enter the for loop.

- to put the for loop inside updateForm(), It does not run.
- to put create a demo function, I could access and pass data to
  different functions.
- to change the name of variables, it does not work.

Comment: `org.legnth` rather than `org.length`, check your spelling.

Comment: Sorry for being so careless and silly.
Yes. you are correct. Incorrect spelling !!
I write on google script online platform, it didn't warn me wrong spelling, may I kow what software/ IDE you use for syntax error ?

Comment: I don't use a different IDE, just happened to notice it when I looked at the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typo that caused the mistake.....
**org.legnth** --> should be **org.length**
I am attempting to get the array length

```
 function uList(org, chg){
    //return a unique list
    var org ;
    var chg ;
    var temp ;

    for(var i=0;i<=org.legnth;i++){ 
      for(var j=0;j<=chg.length;j++){
         if(org[i][0]==chg[j][0]){
           if(temp.length>0) {temp.pop();}

         }else{
           temp.push(org[i][0]);


         }
      }

    }
      return temp;
 }
```

Change to

```
 function uList(org, chg){
    //return a unique list
    var org ;
    var chg ;
    var temp=[] ;

    for(var i=0;i<=org.legnth;i++){ 
      for(var j=0;j<=chg.length;j++){
         if(org[i]==chg[j]){
           if(temp.length>0) {temp.pop();}

         }else{
           temp.push(org[i][0]);


         }
      }

    }
      return temp;
 }
```

Change log:

- org.length, a typo rectification
- remove [0] behind org and chg , since its 1D array
- define var temp as array as my first items need to be pushed.

2020-01-30 0023 GMT+8